# Installation stuck at welcome screen

Tags: 11.10, installation

I decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10, installed it onto a live USB-stick and restarted my computer. I ran Ubuntu from the stick, and clicked on the Install button  Ubuntu application.

After completing the installation steps (set language, time, keyboard e.t.c), I get the the Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 screen and the cursor shows that it's loading something but nothing else is going on. There's no progress bar or anything. What's going on?

Comment: It may be waiting for some input from you that you have not noticed. To speed up the install a lot of activity takes place while we are completing those installation steps and this can cause us to think that the install is taking place and then we do not notice the message that asks us to confirm the installation or something like that.

Comment: Did there something happen in the end? I have the same problem and would like to know if it will go on.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Alternate Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download#alternate), or try just leaving it be for 1/2 an hour and see if something happens.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem, and after some time ( ~10 min. ) it stopped with an error message and asked for a device or partition to install the boot loader. If your not using a mac you will also hear your machine working, and its an indicator something is happening in the background. Some kind of weird there is no progress bar or any dialog telling whats going on!

**EDIT**:

After repeating the process for some times without any success, I just deleted all files from the usb drive and created another version. It happened on the version 14 and I downloaded version 15 and tryied this. I also switched to another Hard drive because the version before had windows on it with a RAID 0.